# Tour of Go: Understanding the stringers exercise

Tags: go, interface

I was doing [this exercise on stringers](https://tour.golang.org/methods/18).

Problem: Make the `IPAddr` type implement `fmt.Stringer` to print the address as a dotted quad. For instance, `IPAddr{1, 2, 3, 4}` should print as `"1.2.3.4"`.

Starting code:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type IPAddr [4]byte

// TODO: Add a "String() string" method to IPAddr.

func main() {
    hosts := map[string]IPAddr{
        "loopback":  {127, 0, 0, 1},
        "googleDNS": {8, 8, 8, 8},
    }
    for name, ip := range hosts {
        fmt.Printf("%v: %v\n", name, ip)
    }
}
```

This was my code:

```golang
func (addr IPAddr) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%v.%v.%v.%v", addr[0], addr[1], addr[2], addr[3])
}
```

And it worked! But I don't understand why. I've gathered that I don't have to explicitly define the `Stringer` interface as it is included in `fmt`, but where in the `main()` function is my code being utilised? Does it automatically run it on any `IPAddr` type data it finds, which is why the map is modified without me doing anything? This is my first compiler based language (I know some Python and JavaScript), so I do not know if this concept is similar to other languages.

Comment: The map is not being modified, so I'm not sure what you're asking. `fmt.Pprintf` is calling your `String` method.

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/ -- *"Except when printed using the verbs %T and %p, special formatting considerations apply for operands that **implement certain interfaces**. In order of application: "* ... *"**5.** If an operand implements method **String() string**, that method will be invoked to convert the object to a string, which will then be formatted as required by the verb (if any)."*

Comment: https://golang.org/src/fmt/print.go#L627

Comment: Thanks everyone. I thought the map was being modified because of the result I saw on printing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`main` uses `fmt.Printf` to print the IP address, which uses the `String()` method if the type implements `Stringer` interface. Since you declared the `String() string` method for that type, `IPAddr` implements `Stringer` interface.

The concept you are looking for is called "Duck Typing". There is no need to declare types as implementing interfaces. If a type has the same methods as an interface, the type implements that interface

Comment: Thank you. I understand better now, but I don't understand the line "there is no need to declare types as implementing interfaces". I looked up duck typing and see that the interface will be implemented if a type has its methods, but I'm not clear on this particular statement.

Comment: You don't have to declare the type `IPAddr` as `implements fmt.Stringer`, as you would do in Java or C++. Just because `IPAddr` has all the methods `fmt.Stringer` has, it implements that interface. Because of this, all types implement the empty interface, `interface{}`.